# How to choose build for wpf application that work for 32 and 64 bit system?

Tags: sql-server, wpf, build, 64-bit, installation

My WPF application Build is Release Any CPU  and Prerequisites are SqlServer,Crystal Report and .NET Framework 4.0 (packed with a setup file together with the application).

**Case 1: 32 Bit System**
When I run the setup in a 32-bit system, it installs SQL Server 2008 x86, Crystal Reports x86. After installation, application is able to connect SQL Server and open all the Reports from application.

**Case 2: 64 Bit System**
When I run the setup in a 64-bit system, it installs SQL Server 2008 x64, Crystal Reports x64, but WPF application to `Program Files(x86)` folder. After installation, application is not able to connect SQL Server and reports doesn't open.

I know the reason that application is installed in `Program(x86)` folder, but then how to force setup to install in `Program Files` folder. I have set build to `Any CPU`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

32 bit version works also on x64 systems.

Don't know if that changed but ~2 years ago, there was a blog post from a microsoft guy saying that, unless you really need more than 2GB of memory you should build you applications always with 32 bit. It is also supposedly faster since more pointers fit into the CPU cache (that's what was written in the blog)

Visual Studio 2012 is also a 32-bit build and if you want edit and continue in debug (changing code on the fly, while debugging) it works so far only with 32 bit. (in the next VS it should also work with x64)

so unless you use huge amounts of memory, there is no benefit to compile it as any cpu or even x64 and a huge benefit if you compile it with 32-bit